# changing axis weight in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to change axis weight in matplotlib (make the axis much bolder)?

```
from pylab import *    
x = [5,7,5,9,11,14]
y = [4,5,3,11,15,14]
scatter(x, y, s=50, color='green',marker='h')
show()
```

Comment: Do you want something like `axhline(linewidth=5, color='black')` ?

Comment: yes, similiar to that which can make all the axis much bolder   @falsetru

Answer (score 5):

You can set the width of whats called a spine (a side of the axes) in Matplotlib:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(np.random.randn(100).cumsum())

# The spines
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), linewidth=3)

# The ticks
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=3)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=3)
```

[image]

Comment: great! @Rutger Kassies can you explain your code at least slightly

Answer (score 0):

Use [`axhline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline), [`axvline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline):

```
axhline(linewidth=5, color='black')
axvline(linewidth=5, color='black')
axhline(linewidth=5, y=max(y)*1.1, color='black')
axvline(linewidth=5, x=max(x)*1.1, color='black')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @falsetru it changes only two sides, i want to change all the four sides , and also the tick marks

Comment: not exactly, still one side is remaining and the right most side does not merge with original one.@falsetru

Comment: @tester2, Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: your code is not perfect since it can not make all the four sides bolder @ falsetru

Comment: @tester2, I added a result as a image. What do you mean for all the four sides?